# Moving an NHibernate-heavy application from single-tenancy to multi-tenancy with multiple schemas

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, multi-tenant, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I currently have a single-tenant application that uses fluent-nhibernate mappings to map C# objects to tables in my MySQL database.

As part of an effort to bring multi-tenancy to my application, I am considering having a single schema for each tenant.  That is, I will have `n` schemas with identical table structures, `n` somewhere in the hundreds.

How can I rig up NHibernate, along with my fluent mappings, so that I can arbitrarily access the correct schema, and without having to replicate my C# objects to map to each schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you can set in the `SessionFactory` (technically in its configuration) the default schema name. The property is `hibernate.default_schema`. So you could have multiple `SessionFactory`, one for each schema. Clearly you mustn't set the scema name at the Entity level.

Something like:

```
var config = new Configuration();
... other configuration ...
config.Properties["hibernate.default_schema"] = "Foo"; // your schema name
ISessionFactory sf = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```